# Multiple SQLite unique columns as one

Tags: sqlite

Given the following example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE shapes(
    shape_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    background_color TEXT,
    foreground_color TEXT,
    UNIQUE(background_color,foreground_color)
);
```

`background_color` AND `foreground_color` need to be unique to insert but I don't want that. consider the row exists:

`black|blue`

and I try to insert:

`white|blue`

it will insert but if I try to insert another row containing:

`black|blue`

it will ignore the insert.

Will a primary key of the two cols accomplish this? If so, do I need to also use `INSERT OR IGNORE`?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Provide all the values (i.e. shape_id) you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the `UNIQUE` constraint from the definition of the table.

What you can do is create a unique index not on the columns but on the min and max values of the 2 columns:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_shapes_colors ON shapes(
  MIN(background_color, foreground_color),
  MAX(background_color, foreground_color)
);
```

Then, when you try to insert the same combination of colors, like:

```
INSERT INTO shapes (background_color, foreground_color) VALUES ('black', 'blue');
INSERT INTO shapes (background_color, foreground_color) VALUES ('blue', 'black');
```

the 2nd statement will fail with an error message:

> UNIQUE constraint failed: index 'idx_shapes_colors'

or, if you use `INSERT OR IGNORE`:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO shapes (background_color, foreground_color) VALUES ('blue', 'black');
```

there will be no error but the statement will not insert the row.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c8eca047645a95fa2bfbc27934c56643).